# mysql prepared statement "truncate table ?" returns null

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

in a function to truncate a table I can use

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("truncate table packed_items");
```

and $stmt is set to a mysqli_stmt Object, but
if I try

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("truncate table ?");
```

then $stmt is set to null and the statment:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $mytable)
```

will crash with error
 
 Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in

I am using parameterized prepared statements to select,insert and update with no problem.

Comment: Why upvote this duplicate of 1000s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot bind any SQL literal but data one. no keyword, no operator, no identifier.

if you really need to truncate your tables dynamically, knowing no name already (as truncating tables at random is obviously a sign of very bad design), check the table name against white list, format it correctly, and then interpolate in a query string.

Comment: Are you saying the replaceable parameter (?) can only be replaced by information and not a symbol name?. Did the prepare method kick me out because it know that the only thing that can replace the (?) was a symbol? The 'bad design' is a development only convenience, not in production code, but thanks for the opinion anyway.  Also if you had  a link to the rule that I am breaking, that would be nice.  And by 'interpolating' do you mean string concatenation?

Comment: yup, cant use table names in prepared statements.
found this:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,269185,269185